# Javascript expandme image click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using https://github.com/nigma/jquery-expandme plugin in for my page, here is [the example](http://en.ig.ma/projects)

Everytime when you click the bottom grey area, the background image expands to full, and click the grey area again, it collapses to the top part of the image.

This is what I'd like to achieve:

I'd like to keep the up and down arrow function as it is, and to make the click happen on the image itself as well so it is easy for people to use.

1) The down arrow should still show on the bottom when it is the top part of image, so you can either click on the image itself or the down arrow to expand.

2) After it expands to full image, the up arrow should show down the bottom. So you can either click on the image or the up arrow to collapse it to the top image.

I have been trying for a while, but no success. Can some please point me to the right direction?

Thank you,
S:)

Comment: What exactly have you tried already?

Comment: I tried to make the the grey area to cover the whole image, but both of the up and down arrows would show at the same time. Then I tried to limit the arrow area to show only up or down arrow. I've been changing css, but not sure it is right way. Therefore I am here to ask some advice before I spent another half day on it. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: also I tried to add the same function to the image in javascipt, but it didn't work, so I am hoping someone could lead me to the right direction before I keep trying blindly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT : i think i got it wrong the first time ..

Edit : please follow the link below .

https://github.com/codeiz/jquery-expandme

i have updated the plugin and now it allows more than one controller
but now you have to pass an array as an argument please look at  the documentation

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added a class to the image, do I have to make it an a tag? I added imageclass to $('.expandme , .imageclass').expandme({ and expandToggleClass: 'expand-toggle' in js, but the function stopped, it doesn't expand the image any more. Can you give me more details on how to target it with your suggestion please? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, unfortunately it didn't work. When I add an a tag to the image and .imageclass, the whole toggle stops working, when I just add .imageclass to the image, the function on the page stays the same as before. Is there any other places I need to change? Or other solutions? Thanks.

Comment: i did actually try it , i will try to fork the plugin to add the feature , but the solution i posted works but it will double the size of container when expanding !

Comment: just put the class of the image in the sittings only

Comment: That is weird that I couldn't make your code work. Can you please add your code to http://jsfiddle.net so that I can have a look at what you changed. I have posted the original one here http://jsfiddle.net/DREaH/ if you want to change that instead. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can change this expandToggleClass to "exmandme" :

// Class added to expanded element
 expandToggleClass: 'expand-toggle', // Class for anchor element that triggers

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm not exactly sure what you mean. Can you please explain it for me?